# On bundle install I am getting gem couldn't be found issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have `macOs Monterey`. I am using ruby 2.7.1.
While doing bundle install I am getting below error:

```rb
Could not find spring-watcher-listen-2.0.1 in any of the sources
```

I tried update gems, Along with removed the lock file. but, exisiting features of the app stopped wotking.

Comment: post your gemfile

Comment: What version of bundler are you using? You can check it by running `bundler -v`.

Comment: It [exists](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring-watcher-listen/versions/2.0.1) in rubygems. If you post your `Gemfile` or parts of it it will be easier to help.